# ADC samples half frequency

Tags: adc, signal, sampling

I'm using a dsPIC33F (Microchip) to sample a 555-timer signal. I've tried square, triangular, and "sinusoidal" signal shapes, but always have the same problem: the ADC samples the waveform correctly, but the result is always half of the expected frequency.

For example, my input is 440Hz, and when I plot what the ADC writes to the buffer, I get:

[image]

Without the lines it is:

[image]

On the oscilloscope I read it as 440Hz.  My sampling frequency is 8kHz (which I checked with the oscilloscope by toggling a pin), and as I change it, the sampled values change to reflect that, so I'm almost certain I'm using the correct timer to trigger the ADC.  Since each point represents 1/8000 = 0.000125s, the above graphs show a waveform with a period of 36*.000125=0.0045, or 222Hz.

I feel like the conversion time should have no effect, as long as it's shorter than 0.000125s.  I'm confident that it is, and have tried different conversion times with no change.  I know it's not the most efficient way of doing things, but to start I also convert only one sample at a time before triggering an interrupt and writing to the buffer.  I'm not sure if that would matter.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be grateful.

Comment: When you checked the sampling frequency by toggling a pin, did you toggle the pin at the sampling rate, and measure the output waveform frequency as 8kHz?  That would mean that the sampling clock is 16kHz.

Comment: Wow, I figured it would be a dumb mistake, but I had hoped something a bit more respectable than that.  Thank you.  I wish I'd asked sooner.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.  I converted my comment to an answer so the question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you toggle a pin at a certain rate, the resulting waveform will have a frequency at half of the toggle rate.  So if your output waveform was a 8kHz square wave, then your ADC sample rate is actually 16kHz, which explains the factor of 2 error.

Comment: It can be pretty easy to forget to toggle twice for a single period.